# Is it possible that if the openSTF is in "use" status it will change when the device is being used by the automation engine?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rethinkdb, appium-android, android-device-monitor

Actually, I need to change the status on each device because I want to know which device is being used or which is not being used by automation engine.Hopely, there is an answer to the question I asked.. Thank you

Regrads,

Irvan